# Large file does not download with jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am sending an AJAX POST request from the `script` inside JSP.

Inside controller i am reading the file from the location and return the byte Array.

```
fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);

        filedata = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
        fileInputStreamReader.close();
```

Then on the front end i am crating an invisible link and downloading the file.

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type : 'POST',
    data : nodedata,
    beforeSend : function(jqXHR, settings) {
        setCsrfHeader(jqXHR);
    },
    success : function(data) {
         hideLoader();
       /* window.open("data:"+contentType+";base64, " + data); */
        var uri = 'data:'+contentType+';base64,' + data;
        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.href = uri;
        downloadLink.download =atcName ;

        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
        $("#Success").html("File download successful");
        $("#error").hide();
        $("#Success").show();
        document.body.removeChild(downloadLink); 
    },
    error : function(e) {
         hideLoader();
         $("#error").html(ERROR_SERVER_RESPONSE);
         $("#Success").hide();
         $("#error").show();
        alert(ERROR_SERVER_RESPONSE);
    }
});
```

The problem is only with large file size >~50mb. What should I do?

Comment: "What should I do?": post the exact error message.

Comment: @Henry:as I said ,when I do inspect element,large files also got transfered. but is not downloaded as an attachment.There is no error message anywhere.The response is also empty,but the response status is 200 OK

Comment: What server do you use? There might be a file size limit or a timeout if the upload takes too long.

Comment: it was chrome browser crash.How to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I suggest to check if there is no cache issue because a timeout should trigger an error callback.

You should add the aparameter `cache : false,` in your request or, better IMHO, you can prevent all futher Ajaxs call from being cached, [regardless of which jQuery method you use(ajax, get...)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/).

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```